# Using np.select in DateTime series - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have a problem using np.select in DateTime series.
Imagine you have a DataFrame: dateframe['id','FLOAT','DATE1','DATE2']

```
dateframe['DATE1'] = dt.datetime.now()
dateframe['DATE2'] = dt.datetime.now()

dateframe['DATE3'] = np.select(
    [
        dateframe['FLOAT']>0,
        dateframe['FLOAT']<=0,
    ],
    [
        dateframe['DATE1'],
        dateframe['DATE2'],
    ]
)
```

I get this error:

**TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[uint8]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a data-specific issue, please post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `np.where` when you have one condition that creates exactly two mutually exclusive groups:

```
dataframe['DATE1'] = dt.datetime.now()
dataframe['DATE2'] = dt.datetime.now()
dataframe['DATE3'] = np.where(dataframe['FLOAT']>0,dataframe['DATE1'],dataframe['DATE2'])
dataframe
```

Regarding the error with `np.select`. Initially store the date as an object datatype with `str()` and then convert `to_datetime()` later. Per the error, there is an issue with the datetime data type in the np.select statement

```
dataframe['DATE1'] = str(dt.datetime.now())
dataframe['DATE2'] = str(dt.datetime.now())
dataframe['DATE3'] = pd.to_datetime(np.select([(dataframe['FLOAT']>0),(dataframe['FLOAT']<=0)],
                                              [dataframe['DATE1'],dataframe['DATE2']]))
dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I've looking for this answer for weeks.

Comment: Greetings from Lima, Perú.